# how can I define a type for error data return in rtk query?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I use rtk query and I have type error with this content :

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SerializedError'
```

and this the code I wrote :

```
const { data, isError, isSuccess, isLoading, error } = useGetClerkListQuery({
        page,
        count: value,
        order_by: orderBy,
        search: searchTerm,
    })
    
    if (isError && error) {
        toast.error(error.data.status.message)
    }
```

also this is my rtk mutation:

```
getClerkList: builder.query<{ result: IClerkList }, IClerkParamsType>({
            query: params => {
                return {
                    url: '/clerk/list/',
                    params,
                }
            },
            providesTags: ['clerk'],
        }),
```

Comment: please provide minimum reproducible example

Comment: @captain-yossarian what info you need? this error occurs on error.data in if condition

Comment: In order to help you, I would like to reproduce this error. It will be easier for me to fix and publish my code as an answer because I will be able to test it. Without reproducible example I can only guess what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to narrow the error type down to FetchBaseQueryError first:

```
if (isError && error && 'status' in error) {
```

But generally note, that the data returned from the server will be `unknown` and you have to verify that it has the right structure and then manually cast it.
It's an error after all, so also something unexpected could have wrong and it could have an unexpected structure as a result.